# Opening an interactive terminal from ranger

Tags: terminal, interactive, ranger

Let's say I want to open xfce4-terminal from ranger with a keybind, like

```
map XX shell myterm
```

Is it possible? How?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? If you run `xfce4-terminal` it should open but ranger would block.

Answer (score 0):

In rc.conf

```
map x terminal
```

Now when you press the key x on ranger, it will open the terminal you set in the env var TERMCMD.